# How to set or reset checkAll by checking and unchecking of check boxes in a list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]

I am working with array of check boxes for two operations as in image
I am able to set all copy checkboxes if I check CopyAll but
I need to set copyAll if all below copy checkboxes are checked and reset if all below checkboxes are reset. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

create a table property at your model called isChecked

```
export interface item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    isChecked: Boolean;//table property 
}
```

make a check all textbox  with a change event

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="all" (change)="checkAll($event)" title="btn" />
```

ts file

```
checkAll(ev: any) {
    this.itemlist.forEach(item => {
    if (ev.target.checked) {
       item.isChecked = true
    } else {
       item.isChecked = false
    }
    item.isChecked = ev.target.checked
 });
}
```

your table

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of itemlist">
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{item}}" 
        [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked" title="inp" />
      </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a model that will represent your data.
Ex:

```
rows = [ {key: "row1", "checked": false },  {key: "row2", "checked": true }]
```

Then on the 'all' click event you have to change all checked to unchecked and otherwise (in the event handler).

Checkbox values in the markup should be two way binded to reflect a change in the model.